# Convergent Fourier series of signum function

Tags: convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I found problem that states:
Find Fourier series of function $f: R\rightarrow R$ given as $f(x)=\mbox{sgn}(\sin x)*\cos x$ where $\mbox{sgn}(x)=1$ for $x>0$, $\mbox{sgn}(x)=0$ for $x=0$ and $\mbox{sgn}(x)=-1$ for $x<0$  and check if series converges or diverges. I am having trouble understanding how to find values of $\mbox{sgn}(\sin x)$ like $\mbox{sgn}(x)$ which is given above.

Comment: On what interval are you asked to find the Fourier series?  Regardless, you will extend $\cos(x)$ as an odd function.  So the series will have only sine terms.

Comment: I wasn't given interval I guess I have to figure it out and it is probably 2π because of cos(x) and sin(x) both have that period. I will try with that. Thanks!

Comment: $\mathrm{sgn}(\sin(x))$ just converts $\sin(x)$ into a square wave.